# Anyone know why Find or Replace dialogs not coming up in Geany editor under Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: editors, geany

I'm using Geany (1.32) in Ubuntu 18.04 and am finding that the dialog boxes to search within the open file using the Search-->Find... and Search -->Replace... are not coming up.

At first I thought it was a keyboard shortcut issue, but it doesn't work when selecting from the menu with the mouse.

EDIT -  it seems to be a known bug, and the problem went away after disabling the Overview Plugin in Plugin Manager - : https://github.com/geany/geany-plugins/issues/730

Comment: If you fixed your problem you should post your edit as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Marked as answered - it seems to be a known bug, and the problem went away after disabling the Overview Plugin in Plugin Manager - : https://github.com/geany/geany-plugins/issues/730